# Use of OR in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write the following as a fact in Prolog using the format  `want_to_eat(Jack, food)`: Jack wants to eat food A OR food B. I tried to write it as `want_to_eat(Jack, (A ; B))`, but `want_to_eat(Jack, A)` returns false. What else can I do?

Follow-up question: Suppose Jack wants to eat apple, and at least one of bread and cherry. It seems one cannot distinguish And and Or if one uses the following.

```
wants_to_eat(jack, apple).
wants_to_eat(jack, bread).
wants_to_eat(jack, cherry).
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: You'd either have to make two facts (`want_to_eat(jack, a). want_to_eat(jack, b).`) or move the "or" into the body of the clause: `want_to_eat(jack, Food) :- Food = a; Food = b.`. Otherwise, you're just creating the difficult-to-use fact `want_to_eat(jack, ;(a,b)).`. Also, try and keep your variables uppercase and your values lowercase or you're going to confuse yourself.

Comment: that's two facts, not one, as Daniel showed.

Comment: Could you take a look at my follow-up question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is a problem with the syntax: an uppercase identifier is a *variable*, not a constant. So you should only write:

```
wants_to_eat(jack, apple).
```

not:

```
wants_to_eat(Jack, Apple).
```

Next the `;` in an a parameter is just a functor. Prolog does *not* attach any semantics to these functors. For Prolog `(;)/2` is just `(;)/2`. The same happens for a comma: `wants_to_eat(jack, (apple, apple, apple))` does *not* "fold" to the fact that `jack` will eat an `apple`, it is just a chain of `(,)/2` functors. Only in the body of a clause, it is seen as a "logical or" (although in Prolog, most operators have a slightly different meaning than their logical counterpart, especially the *not* is a tricky one).

If you write:

```
wants_to_eat(jack, (apple; bread; cherry)).
```

then it only unify with the *entire* second parameter:

```
?- wants_to_eat(jack, A).
A =  (apple;bread;cherry).
```

or due to unification, you can unify with a part of it:

```
?- wants_to_eat(jack, (A;_)).
A = apple.

?- wants_to_eat(jack, (_;B)).
B =  (bread;cherry).
```

So we can not just write such values in a semi-colon separated list. Normally what one does is write several facts, like:

```
wants_to_eat(jack, apple).
wants_to_eat(jack, bread).
wants_to_eat(jack, cherry).
```

We can also perform *unification in the body*, and then use a semi-colon, like:

```
wants_to_eat(jack, F) :-
    F = apple;
    F = bread;
    F = cherry.
```

The above might not be very feasible in case the are a large amount of people (`alice`, `bob`, `jack`, etc.), and a large number of foods (`apple`, `bread`, `cherry`), and we want to define a *cross product*: so *all* these people like *all* these foods. In that case we could for example write it like:

```
wants_to_eat(P, F) :-
    (
        P = alice;
        P = bob;
        P = jack
    ), (
        F = apple;
        F = bread;
        F = cherry
    ).
```

But the above is rather ugly. We might solve this by writing two lists, and use the [**`member/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2) instead:

```
wants_to_eat(P, F) :-
    member(P, [alice, bob, jack]),
    member(F, [apple, bread, cherry]).
```

The above can also be applied to `jack` only:

```
wants_to_eat(jack, F) :-
    member(F, [apple, bread, cherry]).
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you take a look at my follow-up question?

Comment: @Vladimir: this looks more a case of *answer set programming (ASP)* or a *Knowledge Base System (KBS)*.

Comment: Do you mean it cannot be written as facts?

Comment: @Vladimir: you can specify it as facts like `wants_to_eat_any(jack, (apple, bread))`, and then thus implement logic around it. But perhaps you should first ask yourself: "how to write this in first order logic".

Comment: Prolog can only specify ["horn clauses"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause).

Comment: Suppose I write `wants_to_eat_any(jack, (apple, (bread; cherry))).` But `wants_to_eat_any(jack, (apple, bread))` returns false, which I want to be true.

Comment: @Vladimir: well that's why you will need some logic around it, or use a "richer" system like knowledge base systems (KBS). Prolog is "logic *programming*". It means that there is still some work in *analyzing* the things you have to implement yourself. The advanage is however that in programming, you have control over the runtime.

Comment: Or like O'Keefe said "*Prolog is an efficient programming language because it is a very stupid theorem prover.*".